# Matching similar patterns with a single regex

Tags: regex

I currently writing some tests that validate some data in a specific format and I am trying to do the following,

The field to test will contain data in one of the following values:

Uncached Response, IP and port of the responding server

> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx

Partial cache hit, with IP and port of the responding server

> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx:cached

Or a full cache hit

> cached

I really don't care what the data is, just that it matches one of these formats.

I have an expression to match a host and port,

> (([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]).){3}([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]):0*(?:6553[0-5]|655[0-2][0-9]|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|[1-9][0-9]{1,3}|[0-9])

And I could easily add on a `:cached` to match for that, or even just looking for the cached, but that would require 3 seperate validations -

How could I match any of these formats using a single RexEx? Is there an optional flag? Match `cached`, the ip/port regex, or both?

Comment: There _is_ an optional flag (and you use it repeatedly in your example): the question mark (`?`). Your challenge, though, is that the colon separating the IP/port and the word "cached" is _not_ optional: It is required if both are present, but forbidden if only one is present. Thus, I think you're going to have to match separately for the three patterns (although you can certainly put those three match patterns in a single regex: `(IPPortRegex|IPPortRegex:cached|cached)`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make all terms optional, but that leaves open the possibility of a blank matching. That can be prevented by adding a lookahead.

To make clear the regex, I'll placehold the ip part

```
^(?!$)(<IP-REGEX>)(((?<=^)|(?<!^):)cached)?$
```

Using a simpler regex for the ip (not range-checking, just checking the "x" in your example is any digit), the whole thing would be:

```
^(?!$)((\d{3}\.){3}\d{3}:\d{1,5})?(((?<=^)|(?<!^):)cached)?$
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/EciluNcvo2), matching:

```
111.222.333.444:5555
111.222.333.444:5555:cached
cached
```

and *not* matching:

```
111.222.333.444:5555cached
:
:cached
```

FYI, the regex `(?!$)` is a negative look ahead, anchored to start, that asserts the following input is not the end (ie, the input isn't empty).

Note that I added an alternation (with look arounds) for the colon immediately preceding "cached" to match *either* preceded by start of input *or* a colon not preceded by start of input, which deals with preventing the colon from being simply optional (which would allow a missing colon ie `ip:portcached`)

Comment: excellent! i will try this out and let you know how it works, I got an error on [Regexr](http://www.regexr.com) because lookbehind is apparently unsupported in javascript. `the more you know`.

Comment: Note that if you are using the Regexp object in Javascript, it does not support negative lookbehind.

Comment: Try [rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com) - it's my favourite on line regex tester because it's simple. Are you using javascript at runtime?

Comment: Ohh, i liek that one better :D My runtime env is pure Java, so we are good there. It seems as if this works, about 90% :/ Corner case: `<ip>:<port>cached` It would appear to me as if this matches, even if there is no `:` before `cached`.

Comment: ^ on Rubular anyway, testing Java soon. ^

Comment: Same behavior in java, as expected. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Matt added more look around kung fu to prevent the "missing colon separator" issue you found. See latest edits and new demo link.

Comment: This is exactly the behavior I was looking for... Now to figure out what it all means :) Much love, and happy coding :D

Answer (score 0):

**Attention:** The original regex for `<ip>:<port>` has a problem. The dot (.) must be escaped with `\\` otherwise the regex will also accept the value “10A251B251C251:65535”

I tested both solutions, presented by @Joe DeRose and @Bohemian, and both looks to work great in Java.
Follow below the code I used to test some scenarios.

```
private static final String IP_PORT_PATTERN = 
    "(([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.){3}" +
    "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5]):" +
         "0*(?:6553[0-5]|" +    
         "655[0-2][0-9]|" +
         "65[0-4][0-9]{2}|" +
         "6[0-4][0-9]{3}|" +
         "[1-5][0-9]{4}|" +
         "[1-9][0-9]{1,3}|" +
         "[0-9])";

private static final String CACHED_PATTERN_1 = 
    "("+IP_PORT_PATTERN+"|"+IP_PORT_PATTERN+":cached|cached)";

private static final String CACHED_PATTERN_2 = 
    "^(?!$)("+IP_PORT_PATTERN+")?(((?<!^):)?cached)?$";


public static void main(String[] args) {

    //String regex = CACHED_PATTERN_1;
    String regex = CACHED_PATTERN_2;
    String str;

    System.out.println("Those must pass...");
    str = "100.100.100.100:100";    
    System.out.println(str+"? "+ str.matches(regex));
    str = "10.251.251.251:65535";    
    System.out.println(str+"? "+ str.matches(regex));
    str = "10.251.251.251:65535:cached";    
    System.out.println(str+"? "+ str.matches(regex));
    str = "cached";
    System.out.println(str+"? "+ str.matches(regex));

    System.out.println("\nThose must fail...");
    str = ":cached";    
    System.out.println(str+"? "+ str.matches(regex));
    str = "10A251B251C251:65535";    
    System.out.println(str+"? "+ str.matches(regex));
}
```

Comment: The following pattern worked on [rubular.com](http://rubular.com)  for me. ^(?!$)((([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]):0*(?:6553[0-5]|655[0-2][0-9]|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|[1-9][0-9]{1,3}|[0-9]))?(((?<!^):)?cached)?$